# What is triggering the "Tags" section of Stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Been looking for hours. At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask how does the "**Tags**" section make the blue boxes appear below?

I don't think they are using keyup event trigger, since the blue boxes are not being updated on every keypress.

You can test this by going to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and typing:

"**aadfadasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfsaf**"

As you type, you will notice that the blue box "aadfadasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfsaf" will only appear a few seconds AFTER typing. Not during.

Comment: This does not (IMHO) belong on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably call `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` to run their code 1 second after the last `keyup` event.

Comment: I suspect this is the case. How long do you think they are setting their timeout for? Just to understand this more clearly.. On every keyup event, a setTimeout timer is set? Or is there only one timer that is being reset every time? What do you think is the more efficient approach?

Comment: @Christian: On every keyup, clear the previous timer, then set a new 1-second timer.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a case of [autocomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete). There are many ways of accomplishing this.

One way is to store the list of words to autocomplete on the client end. This is very fast and there won't be any delay (unless you program one in).

The other way is to make an AJAX call to the server and have it return a list of autocomplete words. This is how SO does it. Since you don't want to make an ajax call every time the user types in a letter, there is a delay implemented to save bandwidth and improve performance.

If you want to implement a similar feature on your own website, I suggest looking into jQuery plugins to achieve this as there are many freely available ones out there.

EDIT: The trigger is likely a keyup event as you mentioned. However the trigger will likely wait for a second or so using `setTimeout()` before showing the list of possible autocompletes. `clearTimeout()` is used if another key has been pressed during the delay to prevent multiple calls from being made.

Comment: I am using the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin. I am familiar with other similar plugins. But that's not the point. My question is more towards how the events are being triggered.

Comment: @Christian Fazzini: Edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source code using Firebug or another [web inspector](http://www.webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/). You'll see that there's a file called `full.js`. It's minimized, but you can expand the code using a variety of online tools; I go the very lazy approach of copying/pasting the whole thing into the "javascript" box in jsfiddle and hitting "tidy". I'm sure there are better (and faster) ways to do it.

Anyway, in that file, there are a few functions that may interest you: `StackExchange.tagPreferences` and it's subfunctions, `initTagRenderer`, and `StackExchange.inlineEditing`. I think the last function is the one that causes the specific delay you're referring to, but it's pretty hard to tell.